# Put div exactly behind another

Tags: css

I want to put `.image` exactly behind `.description-wrap`. I've tried using padding and margins to center it but no go.

```
.image img {
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
width:30%;
bottom:100px
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vsdLk90s/

Comment: You just want to overlay one element over another?

Comment: @DavidG Yup. I just want the image to be exactly underneath the text. I've multiple instances of this that need to happen.

Comment: So give the `description-wrap` element a style of `position: absolute;`

Comment: @DavidG How do I re-center it after I do that though? `margin: 0 auto;` doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code and explained them in comments.

```css
.image {
  position: absolute; /* Out of flow of current structure */
  width: 70%; /* To regain the width of previous layout */
  margin-top: -15%; /* Align it vertically */
  z-index: -1; /* Priority reordering, place the image underneath the text */
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/zwfcpxx6/1/)